# Proving that Complete Ordered Fields are Archimedean

Tags: analysis

> **Proposition.** Complete ordered fields are Archimedean.
>
> **Proof.** Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a complete ordered field and consider $x\in\mathbb{F}$. We must show that there is an integer $N$ such that $x<N.$ If not, the monotone sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$ is bounded above by $x$ and converges by the monotone sequence property. We assert that this sequence cannot converge to a number, say $y$. If it did, for any $\varepsilon >0$ there would be an $N$ such that for $n\geq N$, $$1=|n+1-n|\leq |n+1-y|+|y-n|\leq 2\varepsilon$$ by the triangle inequality.This gives a contradiction if $\varepsilon <\frac{1}{2}.\square$

This proof for the proposition stated is from Marsden's *Elementary Classical Analysis*. My question here is that in this proof, we assume $\mathbb{F}$ to be a complete ordered field (which also means that $\mathbb{F}$ follows Monotone Sequence Property. Marsden's book defines completeness through MSP).

However, it seems to me that this proof additionally puts another implicit assumption that the integer number field $\mathbb{Z}$ also obeys Monotone Sequence Property.

Am I right about this implicit assumption, or did the author make no additional assumptions in regards to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming, and tips using the website!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb R$ and since it is being assumed that every bounded monotonic of real numbers converges, then, in particular, every bounded monotonic of integer numbers converges (to a real number). No extra assumption is needed.

Comment: I'm sorry but in which part is this part assuming the convergence of bounded monotonic real number sequence? I mean, the proof is assuming 's completeness,   but it didn't say anything about ℝ. Would it be that since ℝ's completeness is an obvious fact, the author didn't mention it?

Comment: And if that's true, in which part is 's completeness being utilized?

Comment: I missed the fact that you are working here with an arbitrary complete ordered field, instead of the reals. But that changes nothing, since you can identify each $n\in\Bbb N$ with the element $1+1+\cdots+1$ ($n$ times) of $\Bbb F$. So, the sequence $1,2,3,\cdots$ can be seen as a monotonic sequence of elements of $\Bbb F$.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That makes whole lot sense.